# Error about Is operator

Tags: vb.net

> BC30020   Is operator does not accept operands of type Integer. Operands must be reference or nullable types.

The message above is the error is get. When I change the `Is` to `=` the DGV
gets an error but when I change it to `IS` the R.Barcode gets an error.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'get the details of the item
    Dim R As POS.POSDS.ItemsRow = CType(Button1.Tag, POSDS.ItemsRow)

    'next search for the barcode in the DGV

    Dim I As Integer
    Dim ItemLoc As Integer = -1
    For I = 0 To DGV2.Rows.Count - 1
        If R.Barcode Is DGV2.Rows(I).Cells(0).Value Then ' Problem: R.Barcode Is DGV2.Rows

            ItemLoc = I
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On`.

Comment: "the DGV gets an error" is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: What's the type of `R.Barcode`?

Answer (score 0):

The `Is` operator checks reference types. If you are looking for equality, then cast both sides of the = to the same data type assuming you are surer than sure of the data type. For example...

```
If CInt(R.Barcode) = CInt(DGV2.Rows**(I).Cells(0).Value) Then
```

If you are only hoping they are the same data type then use `.TryParse`.

```
Dim intBarcode As Integer
 Dim intDGV As Integer
 If Integer.TryParse(R.Barcode, intBarcode) Then
       If Integer.TryParse(DGV2.Rows(I).Cells(0).Value, intDGV) Then
```